# Getting PropertyName of binding from parent Entry control

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a reusable `Entry` control for Xamarin Forms.  I have been piecing this together from a few articles and posts from here and there.

The problem I have is getting my `EntryValidationBehavior` class to know the property name of the ViewModel that the `Entry` control is bound to. Please see the `?????` placeholder in `EntryValidationBehavior.AssociatedObject_OnUnfocused` below.

I am only new to Xamarin and I'm still getting up to speed, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The relevant parts of my code are as follows, please let me know if you need any more detail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyProject.Controls;assembly=MyProject"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      x:Class="MyProject.Controls.FormEntry"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" FontAttributes="Bold" x:Name="TitleLabel"/>
    <Entry Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TextEntry">
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <controls:EntryValidationBehavior />
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
    <Label Grid.Row="2"
           x:Name="ValidationLabel" 
           TextColor="Red"
           AnchorX="0"
           AnchorY="0"
           IsVisible="False"/>
</Grid>
```

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MyProject.Controls
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FormEntry
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Title),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(FormEntry),
            default(string));

        public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Text),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(FormEntry),
            default(string),
            BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public FormEntry()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TitleLabel.Text = Title;
            TextEntry.Text = Text;
            TextEntry.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
        }

        public Entry TextEntryControl => TextEntry;

        public string Title
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
            set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }

        private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Text = e.NewTextValue;
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (propertyName == TitleProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                TitleLabel.Text = Title;
            }

            if (propertyName == TextProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                TextEntry.Text = Text;
            }
        }

        public Task ShowValidationMessage()
        {
            Task.Yield();
            ValidationLabel.Text = message;
            ValidationLabel.IsVisible = true;
            return ValidationLabel.ScaleTo(1, 250, Easing.SinInOut);
        }

        public Task HideValidationMessage()
        {
            Task.Yield();
            return ValidationLabel.ScaleTo(0, 250, Easing.SinInOut)
                .ContinueWith(t => Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => ValidationLabel.IsVisible = false));
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using MyProject.ViewModels;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyProject.Controls
{
    public class EntryValidationBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
    {
        private Entry _associatedObject;

        public string PropertyName { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
        {
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);

            _associatedObject = bindable;
            _associatedObject.Unfocused += AssociatedObject_OnUnfocused;
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_OnUnfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            var source = _associatedObject.BindingContext as BaseViewModel;
            var propertyName = ?????;

            if (source == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            {
                return;
            }

            var errors = source.GetErrors(propertyName).Cast<ValidationResult>().ToList();

            if (errors.Any())
            {
                _associatedObject.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;

                if (_associatedObject.Parent is FormEntry parent)
                {
                    var errorMessagesAsList = errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage);
                    var validationMessages = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errorMessagesAsList);
                    parent.ShowValidationMessage(validationMessages);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _associatedObject.BackgroundColor = Color.Default;

                if (_associatedObject.Parent is FormEntry parent)
                {
                    parent.HideValidationMessage();
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
        {
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);

            _associatedObject.Unfocused -= AssociatedObject_OnUnfocused;

            _associatedObject = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI.  My control is used as per below:
<controls:FormEntry Text="{Binding Name}" Title="Name"/>

Comment: Hi, you can have a try with **Attached Behaviors** to check whether it can implement that .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/attached  and have a look at this discussion ,maybe helpful .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234901/xamarin-visual-state-manager-and-custom-properties/60274997#60274997